# Вирусы с контакта

Tags: windows, вирусы

Мой друг подцепил вирус в контакте,при установке нового антивируса он его как бы удаляет и потом в диспетчере задач он виден как Form 4,как его удалить?

Comment: вконтакте нет вирусов. ваш друг подцепил его на стороннем сайте

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что явно не соответствует тематике программирования.

Answer (score 2):

1) Почистить систему AVZ
 2) Загрузится в безопасный режим, запустить редактор реестра. Проконтролировать нижеперечисленное.

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` параметры shell (стандартное значение - explorer.exe) и userinit (userinit.exe)

В следующих разделах реестра не должно быть посторонних ключей:

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnceEx`
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce`
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnceEx`

3) Проверить соответствие системных файлов самим себе. Вирус легко может какой-нибудь из них подменить. Заменить измененные файлы.

Comment: Спасибо) Вчера уже сам разобрался)) 

Answer (score 0):

Ну всё же:

1. Слови handle окна
2. TerminateProcess
3. WinApi, поэтому с любого нравящегося языка